# Spring Data: findByMyListIsEmpty() throws a compilation error

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm searching for a query method that returns a list of objects with an empty List property.

I already tried

```
List<MyEntity> findByMyListIsEmpty();
List<MyEntity> findByMyListEmpty();
```

I get a compilation error

```
Invalid derived query! No property isEmpty found for type MyList! Traversed path: MyEntity.myList.
```

I also tried

```
List<MyEntity> findByMyListIsNull();
```

it doesn't cause compilation error but it gives me wrong result since myList is not null (Empty List)

Here's the code for my entity class

```
class MyEntity implements Serializable {
// some fields
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "MY_ENTITY_LIST", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MY_ENTITY_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MY_LIST_ID"))
private List<MyList> myList;
// constuctors & getters & setters
}
```

MyEntityRepository :

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
List<MyEntity> findByMyListEmpty(); //My problem is here
}
```

Comment: As per reference in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation, there is no such thing as isEmpty or Empty, consequently the compile issue. Nonetheless the isNull is an option, but in the documentation, `in` is used for collections. Could you try to change and pass the parameter as null to see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is no keyword as IsEmpty/Empty that can be used while querying using spring data JPA findBy queries.Therefore, you are getting compilation error-since it is not supported. Please refer to this link for supported keywords by spring- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ - *Table 3. Supported keywords inside method names provided by spring.*

IsNull is used to check against Null values. Since in your case list is empty, I would suggest try using findByMyListIn(List list) method and pass empty list as argument. I have not checked this solution practically but as per spring doc, it should work.

Apart from that, also check relationship between entities since you have used @JoinTable annotation but there is no mentioning of associative entity/join table in your post.

As an alternate approach, you can always write your own custom queries if builtin methods do not give proper results.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was looking for the wrong table in the documentation that's why I used Empty keyword. I already tried to pass an empty list as argument but it doesn't work. I think I will try to use Query.